# Uinitialized constant BaseController error when using admin namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, namespaces

I have an admin namespace as such:

```
  namespace :admin do
    resources :users
    resources :base
  end
```

With the following directory structure:

```
/app/controllers/
        + admin
            - base_controller.rb
            - users_controller.rb
        - users_controller.rb
        - application_controller.rb
```

I have to wrap `admin/users_conroller.rb` in a `module Admin end`, otherwise I get an `Uninitialized constant BaseController` error:

```
class Admin::BaseController < ApplicationController
end

# Works fine
module Admin
  class UsersController < BaseController
  end
end

# Breaks with error
class Admin::UsersController < BaseController
end
```

Any idea why this is happening? Using Rails 3.2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Namespaces map to directories, underscored filenames are camelcased for class names.

```
class Some::DeeplyNested::BaseActionsController < ApplicationController
```

needs to be in `app/controllers/some/deeply_nested/base_actions_controller.rb` for rails to find it.

In your code, there is no `app/controllers/base_controller.rb`, so `BaseController` in

```
class Admin::UsersController < BaseController
```

points to no class Rails knows about. You need to give it the admin namespace *(as your class definition for BaseController also has)*

```
class Admin::UsersController < Admin::BaseController
end
```

The above and your working code from your Question are one in the same

```
module Admin
  class UsersController < BaseController
  end
end
```

Comment: I had a similar problem and it is worth noting that the case should be lowercase on the namespace directories.

Comment: @RichardHollis is there a case when that's **not** true?